# my bash script doesn't continue after ssh

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh

this doesn't run the code which I used to run a program called Design compiler which need some environment variable from bashrc.
`ssh -X mohamed@mohamed 'cd /usr/synopsys/H-2013.03/bin; sh dc_shell'`

Alternatively, when I run each command individually it runs successfully as observed in the pictures.
[the desired code error picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mv0VW.png)
[commands individually picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vogaM.png)

Comment: Please edit your question to include the text of the script and the output that it produces. Don't use pictures of text.

Answer (score 0):

```
ssh -X mohamed@mohamed 'cd /usr/synopsys/H-2013.03/bin && ./dc_shell'
```

shouldn't do?

Comment: Can you please explain this answer, its hard to tell what your suggestion is from this snippet.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use one command to replace two commands:

```
ssh -X mohamed@mohamed '/bin/sh /usr/synopsys/H-2013.03/bin/dc_shell'
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess your dc_shell requires an interactive shell. This can be enabled with -t parameter:

```
ssh -X -t mohamed@mohamed 'cd /usr/synopsys/H-2013.03/bin; sh dc_shell'
```

If this doesn't work, replace 'sh' with '/bin/sh' .